# Get number of non-missing rows automatically

Tags: sas

I have a lot of tables with different column (variable) names, the only common for them is column named **Date**, so I have a lot of data, each having certain date.

To test if there any missing values for certain column I have to write sql query for each table, something like this one:

```
proc sql;
  create table check as
    select Date, count(Date) as date_count, count(col_x) as col_x, count(col_y) as col_y, ..
    from certain_table
    group by Date;
quit;
```

So I have to manually write **count(xxx) as yyy** part for every table.

Is there a way to write some kind of universal query that could automatically calculate non-missing rows for every column in the table grouped by one column (Date in my case) and display it in the form similar to one produces by the code above?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going down the route of identifying which columns contain missing data, as that seems to be what you are mainly concerned with.  I'm also assuming that your variables are a mixture of character and numeric, my solution will work for both.
There is an NLEVELS option within PROC FREQ that outputs the number of distinct values in a column, with any missing values showing separately.  Here is example code, if you want to group your data by date then you'll have to presort the table and put a BY statement in the PROC FREQ.

```
data class;
set sashelp.class;
if _n_=1 then call missing(name,height); /* set a couple of variables to missing in row 1 */
run;

ods select nlevels; /* only calculate the nlevels stats */
ods output nlevels=want; /* output results to a dataset */
proc freq data=class nlevels;
run;
;
```

Comment: is there any solution without presorting? In this case sql is better because it allows just use what I have, but the drawback is that I have to manually define all column names.

Comment: Not with my solution.  Is your data not sorted by date automatically?  Could you also clarify if the variables are a mix of character and numeric, or just numeric

Comment: yes, data is not sorted by Date automatically and there are numeric and character variables in the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

PROC TABULATE can do this for you easily, as could several statistical PROCs . I do it for `_numeric_` here which allows me to use `var` instead of `class`, much nicer output . If you do need character variables, you can do this with class and just delete the uninteresting rows.

```
proc tabulate data=sashelp.class out=want;
var _numeric_;
tables _numeric_,n nmiss;
run;
```

Comment: This solution is rather nice, although adding grouping by Date makes output little messy. Can it somehow be transformed in a way described at http://pastebin.com/0F8ZefGq ? So the idea is not to display n nmiss for every variable, but to display total number of observations for particular date (because Date field is always present) and for each variable display only missing amount. And get the result in one table.